# What is the Vi editor regex for this?

Tags: vi

I have a lot of columns in a table. I want to replace everything in my query:

```
select count(distinct a), count(distinct b), count(distinct c), count(distinct d) from table_name;
```

to something like this to reflect aliases:

```
select count(distinct a) as a, count(distinct b) as b, count(distinct c) as c, count(distinct d) as d from table_name;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to better specify what you question is.

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: `:1,$s/(distinct \([a-z]*\))/(distinct \1) as \1/g`

Comment: Updated my answer, it works in vi

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Your solution worked. I only modified it to this - :1,$s/(distinct \([a-z_a-z]*\))/(distinct \1) as \1/g because the column names have underscores. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s/\vdistinct\s(.{1})\)/distinct \1) as \1/g
```

You gotta put the `\v` at the beginning to use groups.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in vim:

`:1,$s/distinct (.{1}))/distinct \1) as \1/g`

substitute a thing matching "distinct, followed a (first group) non-greedy match on anything, followed by a )" with "distinct (the first group) ) as (the first group)"

Note that the address "1,$" selects all lines in the file. Edit inspired by Jerry Jeremiah.

Comment: This gave me this error: Pattern not found: distinct (.{1}))

Comment: The original one works at the head of the line, since the implicit address of any command is the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ex` commmand `s`

```
s/count(distinct \([[:alpha:]_][[:alpha:]_]*\))/& as \1/g
```

A more robust example using `sed`, only substituting lines starting with `select`.

```
!sed '/^select/s/count(distinct \([[:alpha:]_][[:alpha:]_]*\))/& as \1/g
```